# My Endless background Service Stopped Automatically After Few Hours . Why?

Tags: android, kotlin, service, background-service

My endless foreground service stopped automatically after 3 to 4 Hours, does 'nt get any Issues? LatLong saved in the server continuous 3 - 4 Hours but randomly the service closed or destroy, I  don't know how to handle this Issue?

```
class MyEndlessService : Service()  , DatabaseListenerCallback {

private var wakeLock: PowerManager.WakeLock? = null
private var isServiceStarted = false
var TAG = "MyService"
var gps_status = 1
var editor: SharedPreferences.Editor? = null
var previousBestLocation: Location? = null
var apiInterface: GetDataService? = null
private var googleApiClient: GoogleApiClient? = null
private var lastLocation: Location? = null
private var locationRequest: LocationRequest? = null
private val UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10000
private val FASTEST_INTERVAL = UPDATE_INTERVAL / 2
var locationManager: LocationManager? = null
var isFirsttime = true
var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences? = null

override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
    return null
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    log("onStartCommand executed with startId: $startId")
    if (intent != null) {
        val action = intent.action
        log("using an intent with action $action")
        when (action) {
            Actions.START.name -> startService()
            Actions.STOP.name -> stopService()
            else -> log("This should never happen. No action in the received intent")
        }
    } else {
        log(
            "with a null intent. It has been probably restarted by the system."
        )
    }
    return START_STICKY
}

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    log("The service has been created".toUpperCase())
    val notification = createNotification()
    startForeground(1, notification)
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    log("The service has been destroyed".toUpperCase())
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    val mdformat = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
    val strDate = mdformat.format(calendar.time)
    LocalDatabaseForException(applicationContext,strDate,"Service Destroyed").execute()
    val broadcastIntent = Intent()
    broadcastIntent.action = "restartservice"
    broadcastIntent.setClass(this, Restarter::class.java)
    this.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent)
}

override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent) {
    val restartServiceIntent = Intent(applicationContext, MyEndlessService::class.java).also {
        it.setPackage(packageName)
    };
    val restartServicePendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
        this,
        1,
        restartServiceIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
    );
    applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    val alarmService: AlarmManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager;
    alarmService.set(
        AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
        restartServicePendingIntent
    );
}

private fun startService() {

    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    val mdformat = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
    val strDate = mdformat.format(calendar.time)
    LocalDatabaseForException(applicationContext,strDate,"Service Started").execute()

    if (isServiceStarted) return
    log("Starting the foreground service task")
  //  Toast.makeText(this, "Service starting its task", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    isServiceStarted = true
    setServiceState(this, ServiceState.STARTED)

    // we need this lock so our service gets not affected by Doze Mode
    wake lock =
        (getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager).run {
            newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "EndlessService::lock").apply {
                acquire()
            }
        }
    // we're starting a loop in a coroutine
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        while (isServiceStarted) {
            launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                pingFakeServer()
                handleUserTracking()
            }
            delay(1000)
        }
        log("End of the loop for the service")
    }
}

private fun stopService() {
    log("Stopping the foreground service")
  //  Toast.makeText(this, "Service stopping", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    val mdformat = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
    val strDate = mdformat.format(calendar.time)
    LocalDatabaseForException(applicationContext,strDate,"Service Stopped").execute()
    try {
        wakeLock?.let {
            if (it.isHeld) {
               // startService()
                it.release()
            }
        }
      // stopForeground(true)
     //   stopSelf()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        log("Service stopped without being started: ${e.message}")
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        val mdformat = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
        val strDate = mdformat.format(calendar.time)
        LocalDatabaseForException(applicationContext,strDate,"Service stopped without being started: ${e.message}").execute()
    }
    isServiceStarted = false
    setServiceState(this, ServiceState.STARTED)
}

private fun pingFakeServer()  {
    SmartLocation.with(applicationContext).location()
        .start(object : OnLocationUpdatedListener {

            override fun onLocationUpdated(location: Location?) {
                val sharedPreferences = applicationContext.getSharedPreferences(
                    "AcessToken",
                    AppCompatActivity.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS
                )
                editor = getSharedPreferences("AcessToken", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                editor = getSharedPreferences("AcessToken", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                editor!!.putString("temp_lattitude", location!!.getLatitude().toString())
                editor!!.putString("temp_lattitude", location!!.getLatitude().toString())
                editor!!.apply()
                val att = sharedPreferences!!.getString("Attendance_ID", "")
                val userid = sharedPreferences.getInt("User_ID", 0).toString()
                if ((att != "") and (userid != "")) {
                    if (previousBestLocation != null) {
                        if (isBetterLocation(location, previousBestLocation)) {
                            previousBestLocation = location
                            onNewLocationAgainwithLocalDatabase(location)
                        }
                    } else {
                        previousBestLocation = location
                        onNewLocationAgainwithLocalDatabase(location)
                    }



                }
            }

        })

}


fun getBatteryPercentage(context: Context): Int {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        val bm = context.getSystemService(BATTERY_SERVICE) as BatteryManager
        bm.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY)
    } else {
        val iFilter = IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)
        val batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, iFilter)
        val level = batteryStatus?.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1) ?: -1
        val scale = batteryStatus?.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1) ?: -1
        val batteryPct = level / scale.toDouble()
        (batteryPct * 100).toInt()
    }
}


fun handleUserTracking() {
    val settings = applicationContext.getSharedPreferences("AcessToken", MODE_PRIVATE)
    val manager = getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
    gps_status = 1
    if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        gps_status = 0
        editor = getSharedPreferences("AcessToken", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
        editor!!.putString("temp_lattitude", "")
        editor!!.putString("temp_longitude", "")
        editor!!.apply()
    }
 
    Log.d("Gps status ", gps_status.toString())
}

fun hitApitoUpdate(gpsstatus: Int?) {
    val settings = applicationContext.getSharedPreferences("AcessToken", MODE_PRIVATE)
    val lattitude = settings.getString("temp_lattitude", "")
    val longitude = settings.getString("temp_longitude", "")
    val userID = settings.getInt("User_ID", 0).toString()
    val access_token = settings.getString("Access_Token", "")
    val battery_per = getBatteryPercentage(this)
    apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(GetDataService::class.java)
    val call = apiInterface!!.updateGpsStatus(
        "Bearer $access_token",
        gpsstatus,
        userID,
        lattitude,
        longitude,
        battery_per
    )
    call.enqueue(object : Callback<GpaStatusPojo> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<GpaStatusPojo>, response: Response<GpaStatusPojo>) {
            try {
                // Toast.makeText(applicationContext,""+response.body()!!.message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                Log.d("Gps status ", response.body()!!.message)
            } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
                val dfgdsdsdsfds = ""
                Log.d("Gps sttaus 22 :", e.toString())
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<GpaStatusPojo>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d("Gps sttaus 33 :", t.toString())
        }
    })
}




private fun onNewLocationAgainwithLocalDatabase(location: Location) {
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    val mdformat = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
    val strDate = mdformat.format(calendar.time)
    LocalDatabaseInsert(location, strDate, applicationContext).execute()
    InsertLocationData(location, false, strDate, applicationContext).execute()
    getLocationList()
}


private fun getLocationList() {
    GetLocationData(applicationContext, this).execute()
}

override fun processData(locationData: MutableList<LocationParam>?) {
    hitApitoBulkEnter(locationData!!)
}

private fun hitApitoBulkEnter(location: List<LocationParam>) {
    if (!Utils.isNetworkConnected(this)) {
        Toast.makeText(
            this,
            "No internet connection available. Please check your internet connection.",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
        startActivity(Intent(this, InternetSettingCheck::class.java))
        return
    }
   

     // send location to the server 
  
}


private fun readWebPageBulkTest(location: String, mTemp: List<LocationParam>) {
    if (!Utils.isNetworkConnected(this)) {
        Toast.makeText(
            this,
            "No internet connection available. Please check your internet connection.",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
        startActivity(Intent(this, InternetSettingCheck::class.java))
        return
    }
    val settings = applicationContext.getSharedPreferences("AcessToken", MODE_PRIVATE)
    val access_token = settings.getString("Access_Token", "")
    val user_id = settings.getInt("User_ID", 0).toString()
    var attendance_id = settings.getString("Attendance_ID", "")
    apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(GetDataService::class.java)
    if (attendance_id == "") {
        attendance_id = "0"
    }
    if (user_id != "") {
        val call: Call<NewLocationPojo> = apiInterface!!.updateLatLongforUserIDBulk(
            "Bearer $access_token",
            location
        )
        Log.e("JsonLocation  :", location)
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<NewLocationPojo> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<NewLocationPojo>,
                response: Response<NewLocationPojo>
            ) {
                try {
                    if (response.body()!!.status == "success") {
                        Log.e("Api response :", response.body()!!.status)
                        Toast.makeText(
                            this@MyEndlessService,
                            "" + response.body()!!.status.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                        updatelatlong(location, mTemp)
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            this@MyEndlessService,
                            "" + response.body()!!.status.toString(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }
                } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@MyEndlessService, "" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                    Log.e("ServerSam :", e.toString())
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<NewLocationPojo>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("ServerSam :", t.toString())
                log("The service has been destroyed".toUpperCase())
                val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
                val mdformat = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
                val strDate = mdformat.format(calendar.time)
                LocalDatabaseForException(applicationContext,strDate,"Api Error :"+t.toString() ).execute()
            }
        })
    }

}

private fun getPostFinal() {

    class GetTasks : AsyncTask<Void?, Void?, List<LocationParam>>() {

        override fun onPostExecute(tasks: List<LocationParam>) {
            super.onPostExecute(tasks)
            DeleteLocationData(applicationContext).execute()
            GetLocationData22().execute()
            // testDataAfterDeleteion();
        }

        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): List<LocationParam> {
            val taskList = DatabaseClient
                .getInstance(applicationContext)
                .appDatabase
                .locationDao()
                .all
            Log.e("Database after updation", taskList.toString())
            return taskList
        }
    }

    val gt = GetTasks()
    gt.execute()
}


internal class GetLocationData22 : AsyncTask<Void?, Void?, List<LocationParam>>() {
    var mContext: Context? = null


    override fun onPostExecute(tasks: List<LocationParam>) {
        super.onPostExecute(tasks)
    }

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): List<LocationParam> {
        val taskList = DatabaseClient.getInstance(mContext)
            .appDatabase
            .locationDao()
            .all
        Log.d("GetAfterDeleteion :", taskList.toString())
        return taskList
    }
}


protected fun isBetterLocation(location: Location, currentBestLocation: Location?): Boolean {
    if (currentBestLocation == null) {
        // A new location is always better than no location
        return true
    }

    // Check whether the new location fix is newer or older
    val timeDelta = location.time - currentBestLocation.time
    val isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > MyService66.TWO_MINUTES
    val isSignificantlyOlder = timeDelta < -MyService66.TWO_MINUTES
    val isNewer = timeDelta > 0

    // If it's been more than two minutes since the current location, use the new location
    // because the user has likely moved
    if (isSignificantlyNewer) {
        return true
        // If the new location is more than two minutes older, it must be worse
    } else if (isSignificantlyOlder) {
        return false
    }

    // Check whether the new location fix is more or less accurate
    val accuracyDelta = (location.accuracy - currentBestLocation.accuracy).toInt()
    val isLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 0
    val isMoreAccurate = accuracyDelta < 0
    val isSignificantlyLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 200
    // Check if the old and new location are from the same provider
    val isFromSameProvider: Boolean =
        isSameProvider(location.provider, currentBestLocation.provider)
    // Determine location quality using a combination of timeliness and accuracy
    if (isMoreAccurate) {
        return true
    } else if (isNewer && !isLessAccurate) {
        return true
    } else if (isNewer && !isSignificantlyLessAccurate && isFromSameProvider) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}


/**
 * Checks whether two providers are the same
 */
private fun isSameProvider(provider1: String?, provider2: String?): Boolean {
    return if (provider1 == null) {
        provider2 == null
    } else provider1 == provider2
}

private fun createNotification(): Notification {
    val notificationChannelId = "ENDLESS SERVICE CHANNEL"

    // depending on the Android API that we're dealing with we will have
    // to use a specific method to create the notification
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            notificationChannelId,
            "Endless Service notifications channel",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        ).let {
            it.description = "Endless Service channel"
            it.enableLights(true)
            it.lightColor = Color.RED
            it.enableVibration(true)
            it.vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400)
            it
        }
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = Intent(this, MainActivityFinal2::class.java).let { notificationIntent ->
        PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0)
    }

    val builder: Notification.Builder = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) Notification.Builder(
        this,
        notificationChannelId
    ) else Notification.Builder(this)

    return builder
        .setContentTitle("Sapphire location on")
       // .setContentText("This is your favorite endless service working")
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app_icon)
     //   .setTicker("Ticker text")
        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH) // for under android 26 compatibility
        .build()
}
```

}

Comment: Please be more specific. It'd help if you created a small example that reproduces your problem. Your class is large, and it's hard to understand what exactly could cause the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Services can be stopped, and most likely will at some point by the OS. According to the docs

> The Android system stops a service only when memory is low and it must recover system resources for the activity that has user focus. If the service is bound to an activity that has user focus, it's less likely to be killed; if the service is declared to run in the foreground, it's rarely killed. If the service is started and is long-running, the system lowers its position in the list of background tasks over time, and the service becomes highly susceptible to killing—if your service is started, you must design it to gracefully handle restarts by the system. If the system kills your service, it restarts it as soon as resources become available, but this also depends on the value that you return from onStartCommand().

The best thing you can do to restart the service is to declare the service as a `STICKY_SERVICE` in that `onStartCommand()`